# How can I load a text file in a specific variable using matlab/Octave?

Tags: matlab, octave

I want to load `train.txt` in to a variable named `train_org`.

But, the following is generating an error?

```
>> train_org = load train.txt;
parse error:

  syntax error

>>> train_org = load train.txt;
                     ^
```

How can I fix that?

---

N.B. The text file loads perfectly without that variable name.

Comment: Read the [documentation on file I/O](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/data-import-and-export.html). You're trying to use a function that specifically works for `.mat` files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting a syntax error because you are using the command syntax to call the `load` function and [you can't assign the output to a variable this way](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/syntax.html).

> Command syntax does not allow you to obtain any values that might be returned by the function. Attempting to assign output from the function to a variable using command syntax generates an error. Use function syntax instead.

You need to use the standard function syntax instead.

```
train_org = load('train.txt')
```